# Using Table to Graph

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame:

```
sample <- data.frame(day=c(1,2,5,10,12,12,14))
sample.table <- as.data.frame(table(sample$day))
```

Now what I'd like to do is graph the day against the count of days, so something like:

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(Var1, Freq, data=sample.table)
```

I realized though that `Var1` really really really wants to be a factor. This works fine for a small number of days, but is terrible when days becomes much larger because the graph becomes unreadable. If I change it to a numeric or integer, then instead of plotting day on the x-axis, it plots the count of day, e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

What can I do so that if I have, say 5000 days, it is still visible well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you use `table` you get a vector with `names` (which are characters), and when you convert to `data.frame` these get converted to factors with the default settings.

You could avoid this by using your original data and getting `ggplot2` to count the data:

```
qplot(day, ..count.., data=sample, stat="bin", binwidth=1)
```

or just use a histogram,

```
qplot(day, data=sample, geom="histogram", binwidth=1)
```

Note that you can adjust the `binwidth` argument to count in larger groups.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a hack for this.

```
as.integer(as.character(sample$day))
```